# $\operatorname{char} k=0$, $a,b,c,d,e \in k$ , then is the polynomial $f(x)=ax^8+bx^6+cx^4+dx^2+e$ solvable by radicals over $k$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, solvable-groups

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and let $a,b,c,d,e \in k$. Then is the polynomial $f(x)=ax^8+bx^6+cx^4+dx^2+e$ solvable by radicals over $k$?

In other words, is the Galois group of $f$ over $k$ solvable?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:**
Is $g(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ solvable by radicals?

Comment: Yes , it is solvable . But um how does that help ?

Comment: hello , um could you help please ?

Comment: I believe the point Hagen is trying to make is that solvable extensions form a distinguished class. Furthermore, the roots of the degree 8 polynomial are precisely the square roots of the degree 4 polynomial. So you have a solvable extension corresponding to the degree 4 polynomial, followed by some quadratic (solvable) extensions. Does that help?